# recently viewed products not showing for guest users

Tags: magento-1.9, products, user, logging

Recently viewed products not showing for guest users. but its working fine for loggedin users. How to show Recently viewed products for guest users? Where to customize the code?

I am displaying recently viewed product in home page and product details page.

**(edit from OP):**

phtml code :

```
if (($_products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()) && $_products->getSize()):
    $i=0;
    foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product):
        echo '<a href="'.$_product->getProductUrl().'" title="'. $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()).'">'; 
        echo '<span class="product-name">'.$_product->getName().'</span>'; 
        echo '<span>'. Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice(),true,false).'</span>';
        echo '</a>'; 
    endforeach;
endif;
```

Comment: Can you please paste your recently view product block code here ?

Comment: {{block type="reports/product_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"}}

Comment: I might have not asked right question...send your phtml code...and where are you displaying recently viewed product on product detail page ?

Comment: I am displaying recently viewed product in home page and product details page.

phtml code :

<?php
 if (($_products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>

<?php $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>">
<span class="product-name"><?php echo $_product->getName() ?></span>
 <span><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice(),true,false); ?></span> 
</a>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

Comment: edit your question and paste it as code, this does not displays right.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this solution from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682483/how-to-get-recently-view-product-for-guest-user-in-magento

Override: class `Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed`

Add this function:

```
   protected function _toHtml() {

/*   if ($this->_hasViewedProductsBefore() === false) {
    return '';
} */

$this->setDisplayMinimalPrice('1');
$collection = $this->_getRecentProductsCollection();

$hasProducts = (bool)count($collection);
//        if (is_null($this->_hasViewedProductsBefore())) {
//           Mage::getSingleton('reports/session')->setData('viewed_products', $hasProducts);
//        }
if ($hasProducts) {
    $this->setRecentlyViewedProducts($collection);
}

return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

Comment: Its not working